# moving a cloud in a draw made with processing

Tags: processing

I am exploring programming by using Processing language.
I wanted to do a cloud that can move through all the screen.
It has to have these characteristics:

```java
circle (60, 100, 60);
circle (100, 100, 80);
circle (140, 100, 60);
```

It has to be white
So first I must declare the variable of the color:

`color whiteCloud      = #FFFFFF;`

then I have to insert the circle values I just mentioned on the void draw () part by writing:

```java
stroke(whiteCloud);
fill(whiteCloud);
```

If you write the code of the circles you get a cloud on the top left part of the screen, but how can I move the cloud?

My best solution so far was to make 3 ellipses with the (that are not the following)

```java
ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 20, 50);
ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 50, 15);
ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 5, 50);
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Please [edit] your post to fix the markdown problems, and ideally show a [mcve] which for Processing should be just a matter of adding just a smattering of `setup` and `draw`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One easy option is to group the circles into their own coordinate system.
When you translate this all circles will follow.
You can achieve this by:

1. call `pushMatrix()` before you draw circles
2. use `translate()` to move to the mouse location
3. draw your circles
4. call `popMatrix()` to exit the coordinate system (and return to the global one

```java
pushMatrix();
  translate(mouseX, mouseY);
  circle (0, 100, 60);
  circle (40, 100, 80);
  circle (80, 100, 60);
popMatrix();
```

(the indentation isn't necessary: it's just to illustrate those transformatiosn will be applied within that group of push/pop matrix calls. This can be handy when you have multiple nested coordinate systems).

For more info I warmly recommend reading the [2D transformations tutorial](https://processing.org/tutorials/transform2d).

You can also group these instructions into a re-usable function by the way:

```java
void drawCloud(int x, int y){
  pushMatrix();
    translate(x, y);
    circle (0, 100, 60);
    circle (40, 100, 80);
    circle (80, 100, 60);
  popMatrix();
}
```

Then you could simply call `drawCloud(mouseX, mouseY);` (and easily draw multiple clouds at different locations). Have fun!

Comment: No worries and welcome. If the answer was helpful consider voting up and if it was the solution to your problem you can mark it with the green check mark as [it's the custom :)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Best of luck with your Processing adventures.