# Making things little in Processing by using width or height

Tags: processing

I am playing with Processing and I would like to know if I can make things little with the commands width or height.
For example `square(300, 250, 400);`
`rect(450, 50, 50, 200);`
`triangle(350, 250, 850, 250, 600, 50);`

How can I make these little by using the commands width or/and height?
Please let me know if I am explaning myself!
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Clarifying what you mean by "making things little" (what are things? perhaps each shape, the house components?) will be helpful for others to understand what you're aiming for. Additionally, if this is for homework, you should also clarify what you're aiming to learn and what your constraints are. (for example you might been taught functions, but not classes yet). It's great you added a short snippet of code to show your attempt. (Overall putting yourself in the shoes of someone who knows nothing of what you attempt to do will help you better explain and also clarify goals for yourself too).

Answer (score 1):

In the examples above you are using constants for the width height.
You can use variables to dynamically.

Here's a basic example drawing a rectangle which changes width, height based when you drag the mouse:

```java
int rectWidth  = 50;
int rectHeight = 200;

void setup(){
  size(300, 300);
  background(255);
}

void draw(){
  rect(50, 50, rectWidth, rectHeight);
}

void mouseDragged(){
  rectWidth  = mouseX;
  rectHeight = mouseY;
}
```

You could use a similar approach with your shapes and a scale factor, through that would not take into account aspect ratios:

```java
float scaleX  = 1.0;
float scaleY  = 1.0;

void setup(){
  size(900, 900);
}

void draw(){
  background(255);
  square(300, 250, 400 * scaleX);
  rect(450, 50, 50 * scaleX, 200 * scaleY);
  triangle(350 * scaleX, 250 * scaleY, 
           850 * scaleX, 250 * scaleY, 
           600 * scaleY, 50 * scaleY);
}

void mouseDragged(){
  scaleX = map(mouseX, 0, width, 0.0, 3.0);
  scaleY = map(mouseY, 0, height, 0.0, 3.0);
}
```

If you want to have fun with random looking shapes this could be good, otherwise you need to take use a more consistent approach to scaling:

```java
void setup(){
  size(900, 900);
}

void draw(){
  background(255);
  float houseScale = map(mouseX, 0, width, 0.0, 3.0);
  drawHouse(houseScale);
}

void drawHouse(float scaleValue){
  pushMatrix();
    scale(scaleValue);
    square(397, 250, 400); 
    rect(464, 50, 50, 200); 
    triangle(350, 250, 850, 250, 600, 50); 
  popMatrix();
}
```

Note that the above doesn't take into account the x,y position of each shape, therefore the pivot/origin of each shape isn't respect, hence not scaling from the centre.

In [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77512264/moving-a-cloud-in-a-draw-made-with-processing) I also mentioned [encapsulating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)) drawing instructions into a re-usable function. You could take this approach, exposing parameters/arguments to control how you draw a house (and internally calculate how to offset each coordinate to draw from centre, etc.):

```java
void setup(){
  size(900, 900);
}

void draw(){
  background(255);
  drawHouse(width * 0.5, height * 0.5, //x, y
            map(mouseX, 0, width, 100, 300), // wall size
            map(mouseY, 0, height, 50, 250),
            50); // roof height);
}

void drawHouse(float x, float y, float wallSize, float roofHeight, float chimneyHeight){
  float originX = x - (wallSize * 0.5);
  float originY = y - (wallSize * 0.5);
  // make the roof 120% the width of the walls
  float roofWidthRatio = 1.2;
  float roofWidth = wallSize * roofWidthRatio;
  float roofHalfDifference = (roofWidth - wallSize) * 0.5;
  float roofBaseXMin = originX - roofHalfDifference;
  float roofBaseXMax = originX + wallSize + roofHalfDifference;
  // chimney location and size
  float chimneyXRatio = 0.25; // a percentage of where horizontall on the roof to place the chimney
  float chimneyWidth = wallSize * 0.12;
  float chimneyX = lerp(roofBaseXMin, roofBaseXMax, chimneyXRatio) - chimneyWidth * 0.5;
  float chimneyY = originY - (roofHeight * 0.25) - chimneyHeight;
  // draw walls
  square(originX, originY, wallSize); 
  // draw chimney
  rect(chimneyX, chimneyY, chimneyWidth, chimneyHeight); 
  // draw roof
  triangle(roofBaseXMin, originY, // left base point
           roofBaseXMax, originY,// right base point
           originX + (wallSize * 0.5), originY - roofHeight); // tip top 

}
```

You can also play with variation in a `for` loop:

```java
void setup(){
  size(900, 900);
  
  background(255);
 
  int numHouses = 9;
  float houseWidth = width / numHouses;
  for(int i = 0 ; i < numHouses; i++){
    float x = houseWidth * i + (houseWidth * 0.5);
    float y = random(height - 100, height - 120);
    float w = random(houseWidth - 50, houseWidth + 10);
    float h = random(100, 150);
    float c = random(50, 100);
    drawHouse(x, y, w, h, c);
  }
}


void drawHouse(float x, float y, float wallSize, float roofHeight, float chimneyHeight){
  float originX = x - (wallSize * 0.5);
  float originY = y - (wallSize * 0.5);
  // make the roof 120% the width of the walls
  float roofWidthRatio = 1.2;
  float roofWidth = wallSize * roofWidthRatio;
  float roofHalfDifference = (roofWidth - wallSize) * 0.5;
  float roofBaseXMin = originX - roofHalfDifference;
  float roofBaseXMax = originX + wallSize + roofHalfDifference;
  // chimney location and size
  float chimneyXRatio = 0.25; // a percentage of where horizontall on the roof to place the chimney
  float chimneyWidth = wallSize * 0.12;
  float chimneyX = lerp(roofBaseXMin, roofBaseXMax, chimneyXRatio) - chimneyWidth * 0.5;
  float chimneyY = originY - (roofHeight * 0.25) - chimneyHeight;
  // draw walls
  square(originX, originY, wallSize); 
  // draw chimney
  rect(chimneyX, chimneyY, chimneyWidth, chimneyHeight); 
  // draw roof
  triangle(roofBaseXMin, originY, // left base point
           roofBaseXMax, originY,// right base point
           originX + (wallSize * 0.5), originY - roofHeight); // tip top 

}
```

What if you try a nested for loop to draw a grid of houses, or better yet, if you take into account the order of each row of houses and the y position you could draw a small neighbourhood.

Hopefully this is enough to get started.
(For more advanced approaches such as drawing tools, this may involve OOP/classes, but these older answer could be handy:
[drag to draw rectangle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67741843/how-to-create-a-new-objectrectangle-everytime-when-the-button-is-clicked/67766664#67766664)
no ControlP5 version:

```java
ArrayList<Rectangle> rectList = new ArrayList<Rectangle>();

Rectangle selection = new Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0);

void setup() {

  size(1000, 1000);
  rectList = new ArrayList<Rectangle>();

}

void draw() {
  background(255);
  // draw previous rectangles (black)
  stroke(0);
  for (int i = 0; i < rectList.size(); i++) {
    rectList.get(i).display();
  }
  // draw current selection (green)
  stroke(0, 192, 0);
  selection.display();
}

void mousePressed(){
  // store selection start
  selection.x = mouseX;
  selection.y = mouseY;
}

void mouseDragged(){
  // update selection dimension as the difference between the current mouse coordinates and the previous ones (selection x, y)
  selection.w = mouseX - selection.x;
  selection.h = mouseY - selection.y;
}

void mouseReleased(){
  // add a new rectangle to the list: a copy of the selection
  rectList.add(selection.copy());
  // reset selection
  selection.reset();
}

class Rectangle{
  
  private int x, y, w, h;
  
  Rectangle(int x, int y, int w, int h){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.w = w;
    this.h = h;
  }
  
  void display(){
    rect(x, y, w, h);
  }
  
  Rectangle copy(){
    return new Rectangle(x, y, w, h);
  }
  
  void reset(){
    x = y = w = h = 0;
  }

}
```

[a simple UI for drawing shapes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23189470/processing-having-object-oriented-programming-issues/34792466#34792466))